# Decline HTTP requests that don't have the expected structure

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Is there a way to decline HTTP requests that don't follow a specific structure defined in code?

e.g I have a `class` named Request and I'd like to decline any HTTP POST request whose body is not in the same format as the Request.

```cs
    public class Request
    {
        public string Something { get; set; }
        public object Data { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just mark some properties as required and let Model Binding do the rest:

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

```
namespace MyApi.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        [Range(0, 999)]
        public double Weight { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and your webapi will look like:

```
using MyApi.Models;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace MyApi.Controllers
{
    public class ProductsController : ApiController
    {
        public HttpResponseMessage Post(Product product)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Do something with the product (not shown).

                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api

**EDIT**

here's some idea, not even sure if it will compile or not, but will put you in the right direction

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Products")]
public HttpResponseMessage Post()
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
    {  
        var content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(content);
        if (model == null)
        {
             return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "could not read content from body"));
        }

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in model.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (prop.GetValue(model, null) == null)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, $"missing value for property {prop.Name}");
            }
        }

        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I don't pass `Name` to my API, it won't ever enter the action and thus I'll receive an Error 400 without any details. Is there a workaround for that? Since I am trying to parse my response and return XML, I don't receive any info on what the issue was.

Comment: you'll need your own model binding. Something close to What's available on Azure functions. Basically you need to read the content of the request and try to parse it by yourself, if it fails, get which information is missing